# Unity: 3D movement/Collision detection failure (AddForce, MovePosition, transform.localPosition)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, position, gameobject, rigid-bodies

**Problem:**
If I get the movement to work correctly, then the collision meshes are not detected. If I get the collision meshes detected, then the movement doesn't work correctly.

**Brief summary of project:**
I have a 3D environment with non-moveable objects (with collider meshes) and a moveable gameobject (rigid body with x2 box colliders) that I am controlling using haptic devices (basically a 3D joystick) through a UDP connection in an C++ app that I have put together and is running while the Unity application runs. The communication between the haptic devices and unity is perfectly fine. I am using the position information passed from the haptic device as my variables for moving my gameobject.  Again, The position data arrives to Unity just fine; the method for using the position data with appropriate conditions and functions within Unity is where I am currently stuck.

**Things I've tried:**
If I use **transform.localPosition** (hapticDevicePosition); then the movement is great, but it ignores the colliders and passes through everything. I read online and understand that transform.localPosition will basically move my object on top of other objects without regards to physics. I also read that I may be able to introduce a ray that is like 0.000001 in front of my object such that it prevents movement if the ray interacts with any other object. This might be a way to still be able to use transform.localPosition? I'm not sure and I've never used rays so it would be difficult for me to set that script up correctly.

I've tried **AddForce**. This behaves very oddly. It only gives me 2 force outputs instead of 3...i.e., I can only move in 2 of the 3 axis. I don't understand why its behaving this way. The colliders are detected, however.

I've tried **rb.MovePosition** (rb.position + posX + posY + posZ) and various combinations of *Time.timeDelay and *speed as well. This also doesn't work correctly. The colliders are detected, but the movement either doesn't work at all, or is not working correctly.

**Conclusion:**
I've played with my script for the last 4 hours and some (not all) of the things that I attempted are commented out so they are still visible (please see code attached below). I will be reading more online explanations and trying out different code and update here if I work out a solution.  If anyone has some pointers or suggestions, in the meantime, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks!

```
using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;

 public class FalconPegControl_2 : MonoBehaviour {

     // Define needed variables
     private TestUDPConnection udpListener;

     public Vector3 realObjectCurrentPos;
     private Vector3 realObjectLastPos;

     public Vector3 realObjectCurrentRot;
     private Vector3 realObjectLastRot;

     public Vector3 realObjectPosChange;
     public Vector3 realObjectRotChange;

     private Quaternion rotation;
     //public float pi = 3.14f;

     private Rigidbody rb;
     private int control = 0;
     public bool collisionOccurred = false;

     //public float thrust = 1000; 

     //public CalibrationManager calibrationManager;

     // Use this for initialization
     void Start () {
         udpListener = GetComponentInParent<TestUDPConnection>();
         collisionOccurred = false;
         rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
         SharedRefs.falconPegControl = this;
     }

     public void OffControl ()
     {
         control = 0;
     }

     public void CollisionDuplicateFix ()
     {
         collisionOccurred = true;
     }

     // Update is called once per frame
     void FixedUpdate () {

         //WITHOUT UNITY AXIS CONVERSION:
         //realObjectCurrentPos[0] = udpListener.xPosReal; //[m]
         //realObjectCurrentPos[1] = udpListener.yPosReal; //[m]
         //realObjectCurrentPos[2] = udpListener.zPosReal; //[m]

         //===============================
         //Unity axis conversions:
         //CHAI3D --> Unity
         //(x, y, z) --> (x, -z, y)
         //CHAI3D: realObjectCurrentPos[0], [1], [2] is CHIA3D (x, y, z)
         //Also, to compensate for the workspace available to the Falcon Device (~0.04, ~0.06, ~0.06)
         //adding a value of x10 allows it to reach the default hemisphere successfully
         //updated comment: the sign values that work (-, +, -)
         //===============================

         //Unity conversion for rotation (using Falcon devices)
         //Since one falcon is for translation and the other is for rotation,
         //the rotation information is a conversion of translational information
         //in other words, max range of (~0.04, ~0.06, ~0.06) has been converted into a max range of (90, 90, 90)
         //using basic algebra (i.e., (90/0.04))
         //thus giving the user the full range of 180 degrees (from 90 degrees to -90 degrees)

         realObjectCurrentPos[0] = udpListener.xPosReal * (-5); //[m]
         realObjectCurrentPos[1] = udpListener.zPosReal * (5); //[m]
         realObjectCurrentPos[2] = udpListener.yPosReal * (-5); //[m]


         realObjectCurrentRot [0] = udpListener.xRot * (90f / 0.04f); //degrees
         realObjectCurrentRot [1] = udpListener.yRot * (90f / 0.06f); //degrees
         realObjectCurrentRot [2] = udpListener.zRot * (90f / 0.06f); //degrees


         if (Input.GetKeyDown ("1")) {
             control = 1;
             SharedRefs.stopWatch.startTimer ();
         }

         if (Input.GetKeyDown ("space")) 
         {
             OffControl ();
         }

         if (control==1)
         {

             Vector3 posUnity = new Vector3 (realObjectCurrentPos[0], realObjectCurrentPos[1], realObjectCurrentPos[2]);
             rb.AddForce (posUnity);

             //Vector3 tempVect = new Vector3(realObjectCurrentPos[0], realObjectCurrentPos[1], realObjectCurrentPos[2]);                 
             //Vector3 startPoint = new Vector3 (0f, 0.0225f, 0f);
             //tempVect = tempVect * speed * Time.deltaTime;

             //transform.localPosition = realObjectCurrentPos; //[m]



             //var unityX = Vector3.Scale (posTemp, Vector3.right);
             //var unityY = Vector3.Scale (posTemp, Vector3.up);
             //var unityZ = Vector3.Scale (posTemp, Vector3.forward);

             //Vector3 unityX = new Vector3 (Vector3.Scale (posTemp, Vector3.right), Vector3.Scale (posTemp, Vector3.up), Vector3.Scale (posTemp, Vector3.forward));
             //Vector3 unityY = new Vector3 (Vector3.Scale (posTemp, Vector3.up));
             //Vector3 unityZ = new Vector3 (Vector3.Scale (posTemp, Vector3.forward));

             //rb.MovePosition (rb.position + unityX + unityY + unityZ);
             //transform.localPosition = (startPoint + tempVect); //[m]

             transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(realObjectCurrentRot); //[m]

             realObjectLastPos = realObjectCurrentPos;//[m]
             realObjectLastRot = realObjectCurrentRot;//[m]

             realObjectPosChange = realObjectCurrentPos - realObjectLastPos; //[m]
             realObjectRotChange = realObjectCurrentRot - realObjectLastRot;


         }
         else if (control==0) 
         {
             Vector3 stop = new Vector3 (0, 0, 0);
             rb.constraints =  RigidbodyConstraints.FreezePositionZ | RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotationZ;
             rb.constraints =  RigidbodyConstraints.FreezePositionX | RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotationX;
             rb.constraints =  RigidbodyConstraints.FreezePositionX | RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotationX;
             rb.velocity = (stop);
         }
     }
 }
```

Also, updated from @Ali Baba's comments:
I haven't had time to test the other methods yet, but by using AddForce and playing with the drag and a force modifier variable, I was able to get control over all three axes (actually 6DOF because I also have rotational control from a 2nd external device) and I also have much better control over my gameobject than before (specifically due to the drag and force modifier variable adjustments).  This may be the best solution, but I originally needed to get my position to change based on the position of the external devices that I am using.  I'm adding a basic, slimmed down, adjusted code which uses AddForce and allows for keycontrol adjustments of the drag and my force modifier variable in case other beginners see this thread also.  In the meantime, I will try to get the other functions (MovePosition, etc) working and update on the results.

Slim, basic drag/variable testing code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Real_Controller : MonoBehaviour {

    // Define needed variables
    private TestUDPConnection udpListener;
    public Vector3 realObjectCurrentPos;
    public Vector3 realObjectCurrentRot;
    private Quaternion rotation;
    private Rigidbody rb;
    private float increaseForce = 23;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        udpListener = GetComponentInParent<TestUDPConnection>();
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
        rb.drag = 1.24f;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate () {

        if (Input.GetKeyDown ("q")) 
        {
            rb.drag -= 0.1f;
            Debug.Log ("drag is: " + rb.drag);
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown ("w")) 
        {
            rb.drag += 0.1f;
            Debug.Log ("drag is: " + rb.drag);
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown ("a")) {
            increaseForce -= 1f;
            Debug.Log ("increased force is: " + increaseForce);
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown ("s")) {
            increaseForce += 1f;
            Debug.Log ("increase force is: " + increaseForce);
        }



        realObjectCurrentPos[0] = udpListener.xPosReal * (-increaseForce); //[m]
        realObjectCurrentPos[1] = udpListener.zPosReal * (increaseForce); //[m]
        realObjectCurrentPos[2] = udpListener.yPosReal * (-increaseForce); //[m]



        Vector3 forceDirection = realObjectCurrentPos - transform.localPosition;
        rb.AddForce (forceDirection * forceDirection.magnitude);



        realObjectCurrentRot [0] = udpListener.xRot * (90f / 0.04f); //degrees
        realObjectCurrentRot [1] = udpListener.yRot * (90f / 0.06f); //degrees
        realObjectCurrentRot [2] = udpListener.zRot * (90f / 0.06f); //degrees


        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(realObjectCurrentRot); //[m]


    }
}
```

Comment: Greetings, May I ask what are your parameters for your RigidBody and physics?
Does it use gravity? Also while using AddForce what axis doesnt change?

Comment: Thank you for your comments.  RigidBody parameters: 1 mass, 0 drag, 0 a.drag, gravity off, kinematic off, interpolate none, collision detection discrete, no constraints. Its the x axis that doesn't work when using AddForce (all three work with simple transform.localposition though).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of placing the `gameObject` at the exact position of your controller, you could try applying a force in the direction of the position you want your `gameObject` to be in:

```
 if (control==1)
 {
     Vector3 forceDirection = realObjectCurrentPos - transform.localPosition;

     rb.AddForce (forceDirection);

     transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(realObjectCurrentRot)
 }
```

The force applied here is linear to the distance between the position of the `gameObject` and the real object, so this basically behaves like a spring. You should try multiplying the force by different factors and test:

```
 rb.AddForce (forceDirection * 0.5f);
```

Or scale it quadratically:

```
 rb.AddForce (forceDirection * forceDirection.magnitude);
```

Whatever feels best

Comment: Thank you for your comments @Ali Baba.  I believe that I already tried this and it locked me out of motion in one of the axes.  I'll go ahead and try again and update with the results shortly.

Comment: Hi again.  To simplify things, I added the basic code to a clean 3D environment with a basic cube as my rigidbody and another basic cube as a non-rigid collider.  Using rb.AddForce works in all three axes, but the movement is extremely unwieldy.  Perhaps there is something wrong with my original 3D environment which I will look through, but I still won't be able to use rb.AddForce (with or without the scale/magnitude adjustment) for my specific application.  It is an improvement from before though, so thank you.  I assume that movePosition would work better if I can manage to make it work.

Comment: Glad to hear it works a little bit at least. What you also should try is increasing the rigibodys drag. Playing around with parameters you could probably make it work decently, but it still might not be good enough for what you are aiming for. Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I'll adjust the drag and play with a few other variables and see how it goes.  I'll update if I work out good parameters using AddForce, or if I end up getting another function to work like MovePosition.

Comment: So, the AddForce option worked for testing.  Thank you for your assistance.  I am migrating to the movePosition option now though while generating collision models through a separate application which will be run at the same time.  Ultimately, this is more in line with the requirements of my project.

Comment: @user70711 please see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/405359)